# How to generate random coordinates outside the circle contained in a rectangular region?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, 2d, polar-coordinates

Given:

1. Rectangular region with length l &  breadth b
2. Circle with radius r
3. Circle is contained in rectangular region like shown in below image

[See image here - Red are expecting evenly distributed coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXwEc.png)

Then how to generate random coordinates outside the circle contained in a rectangular region and **evenly distributed**? (in blue region of below image)

Comment: Yash dev, picture shown is  square.  I more rectangular one would be more illustrative.

Comment: Let the range of random numbers be the area of the blue region.
i.e. generated 1-D value indicates one point in the region.
（However, I cannot show the concrete mathematics for calculating that one point... But someone may be able to solve this elegantly.）

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, updated images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate two random values in ranges (uniform distribution in rectangle)

```
a = Math.random() * width
b = Math.random() * height
```

check if point lies outside the circle:

```
(a-center_x)*(a-center_x)+(b-center_y)*(b-center_y) > r*r
```

if not - repeat random generation until condition becomes true (this is rejection method)

[image]

Generated by this Delphi code for reference

```
var
  Hgt, Wdt, i, N, CX, CY, R, x, y: Integer;
begin
  Hgt := 300;
  Wdt := 400;
  CX := 220;
  CY := 120;
  R := 100;
  N := 15000;
  for i := 0 to N-1 do begin
    x := Round(Random() * Wdt);
    y := Round(Random() * Hgt);
    while (x-CX)*(x-CX)+(y-CY)*(y-CY) < R*R do begin
      x := Round(Random() * Wdt);
      y := Round(Random() * Hgt);
    end;
    Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := clRed;
  end;
```

Comment: Is there a solution without rejection method? The reason for the ask, is that I want to generate fixed number of coordinates(lets say N).  Actually I am creating 3D scene, in programming I can loop over till I get right quantity of coordinates but will not be able to do as this freezes the execution. Plus, N can go up to 5000

Comment: I doubt, combination of circle and rectangle is rather hard. If solution without rejection exists, it might be too complex, slower than rejection (which is pretty simple, but sometimes long series of bad points might occur). For large circles (compared with rectangle) we can separate 4 outer rectangles and one rectangle around the circle to diminish number of misses. But I think that it is **much simpler** to generate 7-8 thousands of points (depending on area ratio) and get 5 thousands of good ones.

Comment: tried above logic, generated coordinates are not evenly distributed. Generated coordinates are clubbed together in the same region

Comment: So your code is wrong. Look at my demonstration

Comment: Tried again in a clean project with hard coded width, height, etc....it is WORKING, THANKS !....I have accepted the answer.

Comment: In case, someone looks for above solution using Javascript, here is the JSFiddle link -  https://jsfiddle.net/rq4nvz63/2/

Comment: Just follow up, what if center's x/y are [0,0]?

Comment: just map random onto needed range, here `(random()-0.5)*width`, similar for height

Answer (score 0):

First generate a *uniform* distribution of x, y values in a *square* and reject any `x,y` outside the *centered* rectangle.

*Algorithm*

```
max_dimension = max(l, b)
min_x = (max_dimension-l)/2;
max_x = min_x + l;
min_y = (max_dimension-b)/2;
max_y = min_y + b;
loop forever
  x = Math.random()*max_dimension
  if (x < min_x || x > max_x) continue;
  y = Math.random()*max_dimension
  if (y < min_y || x > max_y) continue;
```

Now test if x, y inside the circle

```
  xc = x - l/2;
  yc = y - b/2;
  if (xc*xc + yc*yc < r*r) continue
  break
}
```

Comment: @chux-reinstate-monica, tried above logic, generated coordinates are not evenly distributed. Generated coordinates are clubbed together in the same region plus in a line.

Comment: @Yash Algorithm updated.

Comment: This works too, but @MBo's answer looks less complex

Comment: @Yash My concern is that MBo's approach gives a biased answer and risks failing   "evenly distributed"